# How do we pass authentication token in headless chrome in google puppeteer?

Tags: authentication, jwt, puppeteer, headless-browser

I want to pass authentication token(JWT) in puppeteer headers, for the pdf view with headless chrome in my application? 
We are using react as our front-end UI. And using puppeteer we are able to generate pdf, but the link to pdf we need to authorize using JWT
How do we pass the jwt in headers, does puppeteer support Auth token in headers?
Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To pass additional headers in the request, you can use the function [`page.setExtraHTTPHeaders`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pagesetextrahttpheadersheaders).

Quote from the docs linked above:

> The extra HTTP headers will be sent with every request the page initiates.

**Example:**

```js
page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'Token': '...', 
});
```

All following requests will then have the additional header `Token` with the set value.

Comment: Note that it will pass your token to EVERY request even to third-party resources (e.g. google fonts)