# Puppeteer - issues passing token in headless

Tags: node.js, angular, puppeteer

Im new in Puppeteer and im stuck.
Project is related to Angular App, on which user is logged in by link from email. 
I need to pass barear token to the headless browser. Whatever solution i found online, its not working. 
Is there any option to pass user object in Local Storage perhaps? 
Or any other idea?

Thanks

Comment: How do you start the Angular/Puppeteer application? All the examples I see start the application with `ng test app` but I don't want to test it, I want to use it to generate PDFs/images at server side

Answer (score 1):

faced the same issue but tried to copy the cookies and worked with me

```
        var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();
        await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync();
        await using var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(
            new LaunchOptions { Headless = true,IgnoreHTTPSErrors=true });

        await using var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

        var keys = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Keys;

        string cookieString = "";

        foreach (var key in HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Keys) {
            cookieString  = cookieString + key +"="+ HttpContext.Request.Cookies[key]+";";
        }
        await page.SetExtraHttpHeadersAsync(new Dictionary<string, string> {
                        { "cookie" , string.Join(';',cookieString) }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello did you try with the api to modify the header?

```
const headers = new Map();
headers.set(
  'Authorization',
  `Basic ${new Buffer(`${myuser}:${mypass}`).toString('base64')}`
);

await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders(headers);
```

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#pagesetextrahttpheadersheaders

Comment: This i cannot use, since i do not have standard login pass + name.

Answer (score 0):

rojaswilmer has already suggested to use `setExtraHTTPHeaders`. Just change `Basic` with `Bearer` since it's not HTTP Basic auth, as explained also [in another question in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55837273/how-do-we-pass-authentication-token-in-headless-chrome-in-google-puppeteer).

Comment: I did tried like that as well, passes in the browser, but nothing is happening. Page is not chaning to the profile one. And i have error ' Token could not be parsed from the request '